# Logarithm of a matrix $A \in M_2 (\mathbb{C})$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

If ($\{a,b,c,d\}\subset \mathbb{R}$)$$ e^A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix},$$
how do I get the matrix $A\in M_2(\mathbb{C})$? And if is $b=c=0$?

Comment: There isn't just one $A$: even for single complex numbers the logarithm is multivalued.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix).

Comment: And in the real numbers?

Comment: Yes, there too.  For example, for $e^A = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr}$ two possibilities for $A$ are $\pmatrix{0 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr}$ and $\pmatrix{0 & 2\pi\cr -2\pi & 0\cr}$.

Comment: And what is the method?

Comment: If your matrix $e^A$ is nonsingular and diagonalizable, write it as $S D S^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal; let $C$ be diagonal with diagonal entries $c_{ii} = \log d_{ii}$ (for any branch of the logarithm), and then take $A = S C S^{-1}$.

Comment: But if $b=c=0$ and $a, d <0$ then $$ A= \begin{pmatrix} log |a| & 0 \\ 0 & log|d|\end{pmatrix}?$$ For example, $a=-2$, $d=-1$.

Comment: No absolute values.  In this case $A$ can't have real entries.

Comment: For my example: $$ A= \begin{pmatrix} \text{log} (2) & 0 \\ 0& 0 \end{pmatrix} + \text{i}\pi \mathbb{1}?$$

Comment: Yes, or more generally $\pmatrix{\log(2)+(2m+1)i\pi & 0\cr 0 & (2n+1)i \pi}$ for integers $m,n$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is real and if you are so lucky that the eigenvalues of $A$ are not in $(-\infty,0]$, then there is  a real matrix $B$ s.t. $e^B=A$ and $B$ is a polynomial in $A$; morover we can easily calculate it.

Proof. We consider the principal logarithm

$\log:re^{i\theta}\in \mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]\rightarrow \log(r)+i\theta$ where $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$.

Case 1. $A$ has two $>0$ distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_j$; let $P(x)=ax+b$ be the real polynomial that sends $\lambda_j$ to $\log(\lambda_j)$.

Then take $B=aA+bI$.

Case 2. $A$ has two non-real conjugate eigenvalues $r^{i\theta},re^{-i\theta}$ where $r>0,\theta\not= 0$. In the same way as above, we find the real coefficients.

$a=\theta)/(r\sin(\theta)),b=\log(r)-(\theta\cos(\theta))/\sin(\theta)$.

Case 3. $A$ has a double $>0$ eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then $A=\lambda(I_2+N)$ where $N^2=0$.

Take $B=\log(\lambda)I+N=\log(\lambda)I+(1/\lambda) A-I$.